# Set disable for textview onclick

Tags: click, textview

I would like to ask, 
Can I disable onclick for TEXTVIEW?

How do I do so?
because I've tried 
`b.setEnabled(false)`, it doesn't work

Answer (score 6):

enable is work perfect for me u can try

```
b.setClickable(false)
```